# How to scrape a google search results page?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape google search results using the following code. I want to take the title and the url of the first page of the results and then continue by scraping the next pages of the search results too.
This is a sample of code that I just started writing:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup


paging_url = "https://www.google.gr/search?q=donald+trump&ei=F91FW8XBGYjJsQHQwaWADA&start=110&sa=N&biw=811&bih=662"

req = urllib.request.Request("https://www.google.gr/search?q=donald+trump&ei
=F91FW8XBGYjJsQHQwaWADA&start=110&sa=N&biw=811&bih=662",headers = {'User-Agent':"Magic Browser"})

UClient = uReq(req)  # downloading the url
page_html = UClient.read()
UClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
```

I noticed that all google results have a common class named "g". So I wrote the following command:

```
results= page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"g"})
```

But after testing the results taken are not the same that I see when I visit the initial Url.

Moreover some div tags such as:

```
<div data-hveid="38" data-ved="0ahUKEwjGp7XEj5fcAhXMDZoKHRf8DJMQFQgmKAAwAA">
```

and

```
<div class="rc">
```

can not be seen in the tree that BeautifulSoup produces. Meaning I can not use findAll function to locate objects inside those tags because BeautifulSoup acts like they do not exist.
 Why all this happens?

Comment: What do you see when you print this `print(page_soup.title)`?

Comment: This is what is printed :<title>donald trump - Αναζήτηση Google</title>

Comment: Try this to get the first title and the link `print(page_soup.select_one("h3.r a").text,page_soup.select_one("h3.r a").get("href"))`.

Comment: It works but for some reason I do not take the first but the second search result. The same happens when I use my own "solution to this which is refered above. The first search result for some reason is unreachable.